# Execute code beyond original screen view with Vim to R using GNU Screen

Tags: vim

I'm using GNU Screen to send code from Vim to R with the following .vimrc configuration:

```
map <C-L> "kyy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".shellescape(@k))<CR>j

vmap <C-L> "xy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".shellescape(@x."\n"))<CR>j
```

(I use cntr-L to send code from Vim to my R window titled "R".)

I can run functions within the current screen,

```
exp_val <- function(roll){
vals <- numeric(length(roll))
vals[roll == "G"] <- 1/6
vals[roll == "Y"] <- 1/3
vals[roll == "R"] <- 1/2
sum(vals)
}

prob_choice <- function(roll, ng = 6, ny = 4, nr = 3){
tot <- ng + ny + nr
i <- c(ng,ny,nr)
col <- c("G","Y","R")
p1 <- i[col==roll[1]]/tot
i[col==roll[1]] <- i[col==roll[1]] - 1
p2 <- i[col==roll[2]]/(tot-1)
i[col==roll[2]] <- i[col==roll[2]] - 1
p3 <- i[col==roll[3]]/(tot-2)
p1*p2*p3
}
```

but when I try to scroll down and highlight another function that extends below the original screen view

```
single_round <- function(sampsp,probs=rep(1/nrow(sampsp),nrow(sampsp))){
r <- sample(1:nrow(sampsp),1,prob = probs)
dice <- sampsp[r,]
roll <- numeric(3)
i <- which(dice=="G"); roll[i] <- sample(c("B","S","F"),1,prob = c(1/2,1/6,1/3))
j <- which(dice=="Y"); roll[j] <- sample(c("B","S","F"),1,prob = c(1/3,1/3,1/3))
k <- which(dice=="R"); roll[k] <- sample(c("B","S","F"),1,prob = c(1/6,1/2,1/3))
num_dice <- c(length(i),length(j),length(k))
outcome <- c(sum(roll=="B"),sum(roll=="S"),sum(roll=="F"))
if (is.null(roll[i])){roll[i] <- 0}
if (is.null(roll[j])){roll[j] <- 0}
if (is.null(roll[k])){roll[k] <- 0}
feet <- c(sum(roll[i]=="F"),sum(roll[j]=="F"),sum(roll[k]=="F")) # to keep track of color of footprints

list(num_dice,outcome,feet)
}
```

I get the following error

```
X: stuff: one or two arguments required
```

Is there anything I can change in my .vimrc so I can highlight and execute a large part of the script that extends beyond the original screen view?

Comment: "GPU Screen" or "GNU Screen"?

Comment: Just to understand your procedure. You are editing a file in vim. You want to execute that in a specific screen instance. To do so, you print the code to standard output in that screen, select it and pipe it to R. Is that correct? Because if that's the case why don't you just write a temp file and use that as input to R ? Also, I'd have a look at this https://kadekillary.work/post/nvim-r/

Comment: Yes, "GNU Screen", thanks. And yes that's what I'm doing. I want to be able to run code line by line rather than as a whole script. Also, since I already have it working pretty well, I don't want to mess with Nvim-R, but thanks for the reference.